# Rails - Search by datetime_local_field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an active record called 'test'.  Each test has a StartTime and an EndTime, which are in the datetime format in a MySQL database.  I have a view that includes a search form with 2 datetime_local_fields:

```
<%= form_for :test, :url => { :action => :search }, :method => 'get' do %>
  <div class="input-append">
    <%= datetime_local_field :StartDate, params[:search] %><br />
    <%= datetime_local_field :EndDate, params[:search] %><br />
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the associated method from tests_controller.rb:

```
def search
  if :StartDate
    if :EndDate
      @tests = Test.searchRange(:StartDate, :EndDate).order("StartTime DESC")
    end
  end
end
```

And from test.rb:

```
def self.searchRange (date1,date2)
  where(['StartTime >= ? and EndTime <= ?', date1, date2])
end
```

I am returning 0 results each time!  I can't figure out what is going wrong.  I have an entry in my database where the starttime and endtime are both on 2015-10-22, and I search with the parameters 2015-06-01 and 2015-12-10.  Why are the matching records not being returned?

Comment: `:StartDate` in your controller is not what you expect: It is just the symbol `:StartDate`. You will need something like: `params[:StartDate]`. Btw the Ruby community prefers snake case variable names like `:start_date` and not camel case...

Comment: I know, the database predates the Rails app and I'm trying to keep consistency with all the other components of the system.  Would you like to create an answer for the question with an idea of how to get this to function?  Thank you for the hint either way, I will play around with params.  However, it seems to me that by the time it is compared with the database values (in the controller searchRange method) it is being passed as a parameter, and is no longer part of the params hash either way, so I am not sure what difference this makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:StartDate` in your controller is not what you expect: It is just the symbol `:StartDate`. You will need something like: `params[:StartDate]` to access the params send from the form:

```
def search
  @tests = Test.scope
  @tests = @tests.from_date(params[:StartDate]) if params[:StartDate]
  @tests = @tests.to_date(params[:EndDate])     if params[:EndDate]
  @tests = @tests.order("StartTime DESC")
end
```

And I would use [`scopes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in the model instead of class methods:

```
scope :from_date, ->(date) { where('StartTime >= ?', date) }
scope :to_date,   ->(date) { where('EndTime <= ?', date) }
```

Comment: I should have specified - I am using Rails 4, so the scoped method is deprecated.

Comment: Then just use [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-scope) (or its alias `spawn`)

Comment: it is returning all records regardless of whether the date falls into the correct range.  any ideas about why that may be?

Comment: Please try again, I had an `>=` where it needs to be an `<=`

Comment: I really can't get this to work.  If I use scope, I get wrong number of arguments (0 for 2).  To me this suggests that both start and end date must exist, but I want the user to be able to use none, one, or both on a query.  If I use where(nil), which I saw recommended elsewhere to replace scoped from Rails 3, it returns all records.  I have had it pass and display the params variable, and for some reason :StartDate and :EndDate are not being included in the hash.  How should the fields in the form look, as far as parameters?

Comment: Did you check that you actually submit the dates in the params with the keys `:StartDate` and `:EndDate` (not nested)? What is the format of the submitted date?

Comment: You guessed it - the MySQL format and the Rails format were not compatible.  I had to reformat the date in order to compare them.